# $\mathbb{R}^3$ and closed set.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a closed set.

I know a way to solve it, that is,

Let $ \pi : ax+by+cz+d=0$ a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $p=(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$  \ $\pi$. Let $0 <\epsilon < d(\pi,p)$ then  $p \in B= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3; (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 < \epsilon\}$ and for all point $q \in B$ we have $q \notin \pi$. So we conclude that $\mathbb{R}^3$ \ $\pi$ is open.

Ok, but there is another way to solve it? a non boring way..., I don't know, for continuous function?

Comment: Use that the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.

Comment: User638057 In your proof you assume $d(p,π) >0$ for $p \not \in π$. Is this so obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by $f(x,y,z) = ax+by+cz+d$. This is a continuous function since it is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ and the plane given by the equation $ax + by + cz + d=0$ is precisley the pre-image of the closed set $\{ 0 \} \subset \mathbb{R}$ under the continuous function $f$. Hence it is closed.

Comment: It's easy too. thank you guy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$. Can you show that $f$ is continuous? What is $f^{-1}(\{0\}$)? Is it  closed?